# How do I save a double nested many to many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, cocoon-gem

I have three models `:request`, `:access_account` and  `:permission`.

```
class Request < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :access_account_requests
  has_many :access_accounts, through: :access_account_requests
end

class AccessAccount < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :permissions  
  has_many :access_account_requests
  has_many :requests, through: :access_account_requests
end

class Permission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :access_account
  has_and_belongs_to_many :access_account_requests_permissions
end
```

A `:request` and `:access_account` are connected through `:access_account_request` model as the request can have many `:access_accounts` and access_account can have many `:requests`.

```
class AccessAccountRequest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :access_account
  belongs_to :request
  has_and_belongs_to_many :access_account_requests_permissions
end
```

I have joined `:request` and `:access_account` this way because I was thinking to connect somehow `:access_account_request` with `:permission` to define a specific `:permissions` per each `:access_account_request`. For example:

```
class AccessAccountRequestPermission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :access_account_request
  belongs_to :permission
end
```

A user is able to create a `:request` to gain access to multiple `:access_accounts` with multiple `:permissions`. Therefore, I need to create a form for a `:request` where I will be able to select multiple `:access_accounts` and then select multiple `:permissions` related to each `:access_account`.

I was thinking about cocoon gem and try collection_check_boxes or perhaps multistep form.

Please advise if there is any better way to design the relations between the models or how could I go on about this in order to create a fairly simple form.